# Install PHP 5.3 on Leonarp - Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: php

I was trying to update from php 5.2 to php 5.3. Basically what I did is I download the php 5.3 Package from entropy.ch and ran the package. Everything installed successfully. Now, when I try to run local pages. For those that are calling mysql queries, I get blank pages as a result.

Looking at the apache2 error logs, I see the following:

[notice] child pid 44038 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Is my understanding that segmentation fault means that I don't have the proper modules.

Comment: Have you properly installed mysql?

Comment: Yes. Mysql is running just fine as I also installed phpmyadmin, and also I can access mysql from terminal. I also upgrade mysql a few days ago: MySQL client version: 5.0.82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacPorts is your best option (IMO) when you want a MAMP setup, there's a pretty comprehensive setup guide that you can check out here:

http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP

Only problem you may encounter when setting up is the MySQL socket which needs to be set in your php.ini file

Goodluck!!

Answer (score 1):

The Entropy build really isn't maintained from what I have seen.  At work we recently upgraded to Snow Leopard and it flat out doesn't work.  The only solution I have for you is to try macports.  We were able to get it working pretty easily using the macports apache + php5 packages.